# Live search data via dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, search, drop-down-menu, addition

I have a live search facility that narrows down results in a table as you type - all works fine.

I now want to use a dropdown to populate the search field (text box) as i plan to have the search field hidden. - I have done this using the following:

```
$('#filter').change(function(){ 
  filterby = $('#filter').val();
  $("input#SearchBox").val(filterby);
});
```

The problem i have is that when you choose an option from the dropdown it does populate the text field but the results do not update unless i click in the text box and hit a key (space bar for example).

I assume it requires keyboard input and thus only updates if i add a space at the end but is there a way of changing the above code to get the searchbox to recognise it automatically?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `trigger` to make it recognize that the input is different. The live search you are using probably uses `keyup` or `keypress`.

```
$("input#SearchBox").val(filterby).trigger('keyup');
```

If `trigger('keyup')` or 'keypress' doesn't work, you might also try it with 'change'.

Comment: I did already try using change and it didn't work, keyup on the other hand did. Thanks very much!